# How to determine offset bits when addressing CPU cache?

Tags: memory-management, cpu-cache

I know that the offset is based off of the line size for a cache. I have seen the example: "32-btye line size would use the last 5-bits (i.e. $2^5$) off the address as the offset into the line" but I do not understand the process used to determine this.

Comment: 1) write the address in binary. 2) take the last five bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to address a space consisting of $2^N$ values, then you need $N$ address bits.

In your example, $2^N = 32$ and $N = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

The 32 addresses mapped to the cache line could be for instance

```
0b00100000010111100101100111000000
0b00100000010111100101100111000001
0b00100000010111100101100111000010
0b00100000010111100101100111000011
0b00100000010111100101100111000100
...
0b00100000010111100101100111011101
0b00100000010111100101100111011110
0b00100000010111100101100111011111
```

Only the last five bits differ, from all zeroes to all ones.